# Vectorize sparse sum without scipy.sparse

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, sparse-matrix

I am trying to do spatial derivatives and almost managed to get all the loops out of my code, but when I try to sum everything up at the end I have a problem.

I have a set of `N~=250k` nodes.  I have found indices `i,j` of node pairs with `i.size=j.size=~7.5M` that are within a certain search distance, originally coming from `np.triu_indices(n,1)` and passed through a series of boolean masks to wash out nodes not influencing each other.  Now I want to sum up the influences on each node from the other nodes.

I currently have this:

```
def sparseSum(a,i,j,n):
    return np.array([np.sum(a[np.logical_or(i==k,j==k)],axis=0) for k in range(n)])
```

This is very slow.  What I would like is something vectorized.  If I had scipy I could do

```
def sparseSum(a,i,j,n):
    sp=scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((a,(i,j)),shape=(n,n))+ scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((a,(j,i)),shape=(n,n))
    return np.sum(sp, axis=0)
```

But I'm doing this all within an Abaqus implementation that doesn't include scipy.  Is there any way to do this numpy-only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Approach #1 :** Here's an approach making use of [`matrix-multiplication`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) and [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
K = np.arange(n)[:,None]
mask = (i == K) | (j == K)
out = np.dot(mask,a)
```

**Approach #2 :** For cases with a small number of columns, we can use [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) for such bin-based summing along each column, like so -

```
def sparseSum(a,i,j,n):
    if len(a.shape)==1:
        out=np.bincount(i,a,minlength=n)+np.bincount(j,a)
    else:
        ncols = a.shape[1]
        out = np.empty((n,ncols))
        for k in range(ncols):
            out[:,k] = np.bincount(i,a[:,k],minlength=n) + np.bincount(j,a[:,k])
    return out
```

Comment: Probably should have added that `n=~250k` and `i.size=~7.6M`.  I think `mask` might cause a `memoryError`, but I'll try

Comment: Yeah, it hangs.  `mask` is a 238GB boolean array by my calculations

Comment: @DanielForsman I am assuming `a` to be a 2D array/matrix. How many columns does it have?

Comment: It can have 1 or 3 columns with length `i.size`

Comment: Added another `Approach #2`. Check it out too!

Comment: Approach #2 doesn't work with 1D `a` arrays (as `a.shape[1]` is an invalid index) but I could make two implementations from it and select based on `len(a.shape)` and without indexing.  It's real fast, thanks!

Comment: @DanielForsman Feel free to make the edit in my post, as needed to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's not a turn-key solution but one that adds columns of a sparse matrix. It essentially computes and utilises the csc representation

```
def sparse_col_sums(i, j, a, N):
    order = np.lexsort(j, i)
    io, jo, ao = i[order], j[order], a[order]
    col_bnds = io.searchsorted(np.arange(N))
    return np.add.reduceat(ao, col_bnds)
```

Comment: `i,j` are only half of the symmetrical influence matrix.  I think this implementation needs full rank, and I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: @DanielForsman Well, obviously you'd have to call the function twice once with i, j straight, once flipped, and then add the returned vectors. I'm not sure what you mean by full rank. The code certainly nowhere creates a dense representation. In fact I wouldn't be surprised if scipy.sparse did something similar under the hood. Also, since you do not need the proper csc rep (`jo` isn't used, and the columns needn't be sorted) you can optimise a bit by using `order = np.argsort(i)` instead of the more expensive lexsort. (Admittedly, having to sort is a bit of a wart.)

Comment: Scipy sparse uses matrix multiplication to perform row or column sums.

Comment: @hpaulj Ah, ok. I was mostly thinking of the conversion to csc which I still think can't be too different from what I wrote. But thinking about it of course scipy might choose not to convert to csc in the first place. Do you happen to know how all those different sparse reps are handled by scipy? Does it implement ops for all kinds of reps? Or does it convert to the rep best suited to a given op? Or does it convert everything to one rep always? Just curious.

Comment: `scipy.sparse` makes a lot of use of format conversions, as can be seen in the Python portions of its code.  `csr` and `csc` share a lot of 'compressed format' code.  Most numeric operations are implemented in csc/r.  The details of `csr_tocsc` (and vv) are handled in compiled code.  A `csr` transpose is just a change to `csc` without any change to the data and indices.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Very interesting.